# How to fix "prefix is not defined" in this code

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, replit

**My Problem:**

I'm setting up a discord bot using discord.js in repl.it. In my config.js file i have set the bot status and want to include a predetermined variable in that status. So far everything I have tried does not work.

---

**What I've Done to Try and Fix It:**

I have tried many ways to include the variable and some have allowed the program to run. However those that have allowed it to run (including this.prefix) have showed the status as `undefinedhelp` as supposed as the actual value of the prefix `(//)help`.

---

**My Code:**

```
var config = {
  token: "MY BOT TOKEN HERE",
  prefix: "//",
  statusMessage: "video games | (" + this.prefix + "help)", 
  dbltoken: undefined
}

module.exports = config;
```

---

**Output and Errors:**

The output should be a status on the bot that says `video games | (//help)`

What it is currently saying is `video games | (undefinedhelp)`

---

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Possibly related: [Self-references in object literals / initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4616262/9902555)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Self-references in object literals / initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use this inside object.

you can do this

```
var config = {
  token: "MY BOT TOKEN HERE",
  prefix: "//",
}
config.statusMessage = "video games | (" + config.prefix + "help)";
```

Comment: Sorry that does not work. Would you like to see the error it gives?

Comment: This is the error given with the code shown above.```/home/runner/config.js:4
  statusMessage: "video games | (" + config.prefix + "help)", 
                                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'prefix' of undefined```

Comment: Just change config. to this.

Comment: I tried that and it is said in my original question. The output is in the output section.

Comment: first defined the config object.

Comment: How would I do that? Sorry I'm a bit new to this

Comment: ```var config={};
config.token = "MY BOT TOKEN HERE";
config.prefix = "//";
config.statusMessage = "video games | (" + config.prefix + "help)";

```

Comment: I have done what you said but now the main index file can't extract the token from `config.js`

Comment: Here is my login code: ```client.login(client.config.token) // Logs into Discord with the token defined in config.
  .then(() => {
    if(!client.user.bot) { console.log("[JPBTips] Don't self bot idot"); return process.exit() };
    console.log(`Client logged in as ${client.user.tag}`); // Tells you when the bot has logged in!
  })```

Comment: Thank you, your solutions have helped me sort the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
const token = MY BOT TOKEN HERE;

const PREFIX = '=';

bot.on('message', message=>{
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch(args[0]){
        case 'help':
            //CODE GOES HERE
        break;
    }
})
```

Comment: Generally, when leaving an answer, a bit of a narrative should accompany any code (i.e. explain to the OP what the issue was, and why/how your code addresses it).